# Save image in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I need to save image from recaptcha to localhost disk, i'm getting image dom element using watir-webdriver, but it doesn't support save method, as watir do. So how can i save image to my disk?
Html:

```
<div id="recaptcha_image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
  <img style="display:block;" alt="Проверка по слову reCAPTCHA" height="57" width="300" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VusSUxF0IYURRcVTVTjJJnUk92j-hXYsuwqvu0m5tvKFzAnwvrHlz-j_Gfqg-sUrHLj3D2DrUYNNg4uvr2BNgZqlK5vpJUJVYkkWo36I4RRmRGkYZru5kBYhzPCCn49KlH6wW_iLw6vIzv7vnhpu6ndqxb-9SkIRrVYyBwN39kg18Lov7Hc">
</div>
```

and ruby-code:

```
cap = @browsers[i].div(:id => 'recaptcha_image').image
```

How to save image file to disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'    
require 'open-uri'

image_src = @browsers[i].div(:id => 'recaptcha_image').image.src

File.open("/path/", 'wb') do |f|
  f.write open(image_src).read
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ruby's [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) as follows:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "the image url" #https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03A....

File.open("./image.jpg", "wb") do |file_write|
  open(url, 'rb') do |file_read|
    file_write.write(file_read.read)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    require 'watir-get-image-content'
    def save_captcha(@browser)      
        img = @browser.image(xpath: '//*[@id="ctl00_captcha"]/td[2]/div[1]/span[1]/img')        
        filename = "#{@path}/tmp/current_captcha.jpg"
        File.open(filename, 'wb'){|file| file.write( img.to_jpg) }          
    end
```