# Ruby Watir-webdriver saving image when navigating directly to the image

Tags: ruby, image, watir, watir-webdriver, download

I'm trying to grab a set of information from a series of pages that are loaded via JS and to accomplish that I'm using watir-webdriver to load the page and nokogiri to parse them.  This is working great, however, I need to grab a picture off of the page.  The path of the picture is generated upon the page's loading so I wrote the following to create an array of relative URLS to the images and navigate directly to the absolute URL of the first index of the array, which is always the image I want.

```
img_srcs = $page_html.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }    #genereates an array of relative urls pointing to every image
imageURL= "website.com" + img_srcs[1].gsub("..","").to_s    #take the relative URL of image at index position 1 (the image) and converts it to an absolute URL
$browser.goto(imageURL)
```

How can I save this image which the browser has directly loaded?  Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if I anything is unclear.

Edit:
I've now added the following code

```
image_source = $browser.image(:class => "decoded").image.src
File.open("#{$imageID}.txt", "w") do |f|
    f.write open(image_source).read
    f.close
end
```

However, I'm getting the error

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/el
ements/element.rb:490:in 'assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>"img"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir
-webdriver/attribute_helper.rb:71:in 'block in define_string_attribute'
    from 12.rb:121:in 'imageDownload'
    from 12.rb:134:in 'navAndGrab'
    from 12.rb:137:in '<main>'
```

Comment: You'll likely want to use the binary flag when using `File.open` (i.e.`File.open("image.jpg", "wb")`).  See examples in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219768/save-image-in-watir-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
$browser.image(:class => "decoded").image.src
```

You are looking for the html:

```
<img class="decoded">
  <img src="what_you_want"></img>
</img>
```

I am guessing your html is not like that, hence you get the exception regarding finding the image within the image.

You probably just want the first image with class decoded (remove the second .image):

```
image_source = $browser.image(:class => "decoded").src
```

Or maybe you want the full list of images and then get the first one:

```
image_source = $browser.images(:class => "decoded").first.src
```